# Need help understanding how to use a switch statement

Tags: c++, switch-statement

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int i = 0;
  do {
    switch (i) {
      case 1:
        i++;
        break;
      case 4:
      case 8:
        i = i+ 2;
        break;
      default:
        cout << i << endl;
        break;
    }
    i++;
  } while (i < 12);

  cout << i << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Why does the last input of the code print out `12`? Shouldn't it be `11` because of the while statement?

Comment: `do while x > y` means it will be done until `x` is greater than `y`.

Comment: This isn't the problem, but don't use `std::endl` unless you need the extra stuff that it does. `'\n'` starts a new line.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way the last *cout << i* could output anything less than 12 after the while loop.  Your while loop will keep repeating the switch until the variable is 12 or MORE.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to print 12 and exit from the while loop change the code as below. Think about the change and try to understand why this is happening.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int i = 0;
do {
switch (i) {
  case 1:
    i++;
    break;
  case 4:
  case 8:
    i = i+ 2;
    break;
  default:
    cout << i << endl;
    break;
}
i++;
} while (i < 11);

cout << i << endl;
return 0;
}
```

According to your code, this is happening because when `i == 11` at the condition check `i<12` will return true due to 11<12. Because of that the program does not exit from the while loop and loop will run again for i =12 and print 12.